# how to keep a custom object in nodejs and use it in later requests

Tags: node.js

I'd like to ask you about the lifetime of a custom object I created using my own class, and how to obtain and destroy this object in the subsequent calls depending on the business logic.

Let's say we have below routes to create, update and destroy our Employee object;

```
router.post('/create', (req, res) => {
  //We're initializing our Employee object
});

router.post('/update', (req, res) => {
  //and will be updating our existing Employee object
});

router.post('/destroy', (req, res) => {
  //We're done with our Employee object and can destroy it
});
```

In this scenario, shall we keep our Employee object somewhere upon initialization to be able to get and use it in later requests, using employeeId maybe? Until when this Employee object would reside in the memory?

Shall we destroy it or can garbage collection do it?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the Emplojee object in memory is not a good idea. If for any reason you need to restart your server, you will loose all the pending (not yet destoyed) Employee objects.

You should instead find a way to save it on disk.

To answer you question about garbage collection, you should make sure that no variable is pointing to your employee object so that the garbage collector can free the memory.